# ¿Como realizar dos animaciones a la vez en un mismo elemento?

Tags: html, css3

Tengo este botón `<p><a href = '#' class="btn anim">SALES</a></p>`

Con la siguiente animación:

```css
.btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background: #ED1C1C;
  padding: 15px 25px 15px 25px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

a {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: slidein, shake;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

@keyframes slidein {
  from {
    margin-left: 60%;
    width: 100%
  }

  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<p><a href = '#' class="btn anim">SALES</a></p>
```

Y quiero añadir esta que he sacado de css tricks(".face" hace referencia al objeto que están animando) :

```
.face:hover {
  animation: shake 0.82s cubic-bezier(.36,.07,.19,.97) both;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }

  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }

  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

Sin embargo si integro una no funciona la otra y viceversa.

Algo aparentemente tan sencillo no consigo encontrar una respuesta en la red. ¿Me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Primer punto en la etiqueta te falta la clase `face` `<p><a href = '#' class="btn anim face">SALES</a></p>`

Comment: Te dejo este link en el que logre simular lo que quieres hacer [codepen]: https://codepen.io/dmsanchez86/pen/ZwNmGz

Comment: @DanielMauricioSánchezÁvila te recomiendo que agregues tu código como una respuesta en lugar de dejar un enlace a un sitio externo. Es posible que el enlace no funcione mas adelante y quien venga a consultar no encontraría la solución que planteas.

Comment: @DanielMauricioSánchezÁvila Hola, Sigue sin funcionar  (respecto a lo que busco). No se desliza y vibra a la vez.

Comment: La animacion de vibrar la tienes cuando haces el ´hover´ del elemento

Comment: @DanielMauricioSánchezÁvila Gracias. ¿Sabes si se podría hacer a la vez? ¿Es decir que el elemento se mueve y a la vez vibra?

Comment: Realmente si se puede, me causa curiosidad que en este ejemplo no se logra, y lo mas curioso que me parece es que las 2 animaciones modifican `propiedades` diferentes, sería bueno investigar más sobre este comportamiento